# Discrepancy between number of expected and observed events in logistic regression

Tags: maximum-likelihood, logistic, expected-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Properties of logistic regressions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16533/properties-of-logistic-regressions)

I have built a logistic regression model with two covariates. Let $y_i$ be the binary responses and $\hat{\pi}_i$ the ML estimated probabilities for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Now it happens that $\sum_i{y_i}\neq\sum_i{\hat{\pi}_i}$. So, computing a chi-square goodness of fit test, sum of expected frequencies is different from sum of observed frequencies. Is this normal, or there is something wrong?

Comment: There's something wrong. You should have $\sum_i y_i = \sum_i \hat{\pi}_i$. Did you, perhaps, suppress the intercept?

Comment: No, I didn't suppress the intercept. Are you sure that the equality always holds?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't impose any sort of constraint on the fit? The unconstrained model fits the means and has the property that the average of the fitted probabilities is exactly equal to the proportion of '1's, so yes, this identity must hold.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake in my calculations. I apologize. Thanks for your attention.