# Well calibrated classifiers

Tags: probability, logistic, classification, calibration

Except logistic regression, are there any other classifiers that produce well calibrated probabilities out of the box?

Comment: Even for logistic regression, if you regularize it too much it won't hold https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/363042/35989