# Why and how do poisson regression and negative binomial regression preserve sum of predicted outcomes

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I am using poisson regression and negative binomial regression to fit a dataset. In the meantime, I discovered that the sum of fitted values of poisson regression is exactly the same as the sum of original values, and the sum of fitted values of negative binomial regression is very close to the sum of original values.

I am curious whether this is a coincidence or not. Does poisson regression and negative binomial regression preserve the sum of predicted values? If so, how do they do this?

The dataset that I am perform the fitting is:

```r
> head(example)
   N3    N1 w        d2
1 157   165 1  1272.929
2 157   233 1  3475.642
3  80   681 5 20867.050
4 635  9281 7 11354.523
5 635   224 3  7782.573
6 635 13708 1 11717.493
```

The predictors are N1, N3, and d2, while the outcome is w.

```r
> poi_example <- glm(data = example, w ~ log(N1) + log(N3) + log(d2), family = "poisson")
> neg_example <- glm.nb(data = example, w ~ log(N1) + log(N3) + log(d2))
> sum(poi_example$fitted.values)
[1] 2272
> sum(neg_example$fitted.values)
[1] 2271.047
> sum(dat$w)
[1] 2272
```

As you can see, the sum of fitted values of poisson regression is exactly the same as sum of original values of outcomes (2272), and the sum of fitted values of negative binomial regression is very very close to the sum of original outcomes, but not exactly the same. Another thing, which I didn't show here, is that both model gives terrible fits to the data (the predicted values of each data point deviate by a quite large amount from their original values).

Could anyone tell me what goes on behind the scene where R is training these two models? How do they preserve the sum of predicted values for the outcomes even when the fits are not good?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16533/properties-of-logistic-regressions, particularly the last comment: "the property that the mean response is equal to the average predicted mean holds in much greater generality for the class of generalized linear models fit by maximum likelihood, using the canonical link function, and including an intercept in the model."

Comment: And noting that the negative binomial is not strictly a GLM...